# Swipe using two finger in swift of Xcode UI test automation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

I have a scenario where I have to swipe an element by using two finger tap.

If I use one finger tap, it's a different output.

For one finger, I can use

```
pressForDuration(duration: NSTimeInterval, thenDragToElement: XCUIElement)
```

But for two finger tap, I know I can use

```
twoFingerTap
```

But after that, how to swipe that element using the two finger?

Comment: This isn't possible with Xcode UI Testing. Open a bug report with Apple if you want to see it in a future version of Xcode.